# How to automaticly start process if porcess was finished or killed. Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

How to automaticly start process if process was killed or finished Linux Ubuntu 18.04? For example I've got process name Test, that process was killed because some problem... I need to automaticly start that process with screen command. I need a script for that, but porcess should start with screen command, and cron have to check it every 5 minutes.

Comment: Rather than using a cron kludge you could use a proper systemd unit file to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a cron to check if process running or not every 5mins.

```
*/5 * * * * bash /tmp/check_process.sh
```

and in check_process.sh check if process is running or not. If not running then start the process.

```
    #!bin/bash
pgrep -x {process-name}
if($? != 0 )
then 
screen -d -m {process_start_command}
fi
```